# Terraform - AAD - Add existing users on group with a specific department

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I need to add azure ad users with a specific department in a specific group.
My first block is to read all the users on my Azure Active Directory.

```
data "azuread_users" "users" {
return_all = true
}
```

Then, for each user who has the "codeur" department, they must go to my "cod-xxx01" group.

```
resource "azuread_group_member" "Terra-Aad-Member-Cod" {
  for_each = { for allusers, cod in data.azuread_users.users : allusers => cod if cod.data.azuread_users.users.department == "codeur" }

  group_object_id  = azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group["cod-xxx01"].object_id
  member_object_id = each.value.object_id

}
```

My errors are :

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on 3_ServiceGroupsMembers.tf line 32, in resource "azuread_group_member" "Terra-Aad-Member-Cod":
│   32:   for_each = { for allusers, cod in data.azuread_users.users : allusers => cod if cod.azuread_users.users.department == "codeur" }
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on 3_ServiceGroupsMembers.tf line 32, in resource "azuread_group_member" "Terra-Aad-Member-Cod":
│   32:   for_each = { for allusers, cod in data.azuread_users.users : allusers => cod if cod.azuread_users.users.department == "codeur" }
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access an attribute for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?
```

Output of the data source:

```
{  
   account_enabled = true
   display_name = "Name SURNAME"
   mail = ""
   mail_nickname = "xxxxx"
   object_id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
   onpremises_immutable_id = ""
   onpremises_sam_account_name = ""
   onpremises_user_principal_name = ""
   usage_location = ""
   user_principal_name = "xxx@xx.xx"
}
```

Comment: The users is a list of values: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/users#users. So you either access all of the returned values or a specific index. What does the data source output look like? Please add it to the question.

Comment: I'm afraid this will not work that way. The data source returns a map, where the users is a list with the attributes from the question. Furthermore, this `cod.data.azuread_users.users.department` will not work as you are already iterating over the map. So at best you could say `cod[0].department` for testing purposes. Also, since users is a list, you would have to iterate over all values of that list and not only the first index `[0]`. Last, but not the least, as you can see, there is no attribute named `department` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems , user stored in cod is again checked with overall users ,( cod if cod.data.azuread_users.users.department == "codeur" ) which is incorrect.

1. Please check to iterate for one user each time .
   And correct the following values with id and each

   group_object_id  = azuread_group. Terra-Aad-Group.id
   member_object_id = data.azuread_user.user[each.key].id
2. I have tried to reproduce in my environment.

Firstly  downloaded azure ad users into csv as below to local drive.

[image]

Called them to local environment and used.

CODE:

```
locals {
  users = csvdecode(file("C:/exportUsers.csv"))
}

resource "azuread_user" "users" {
for_each = { for i , user in local.users : i => user }
user_principal_name = each.value.UserPrincipalName    

 // for_each = { for user in local.users : user.UPN => user }
 // user_principal_names = each.value.UPN
}

resource "azuread_group" "Terra-Aad-Group" {
  display_name = "cod-xxx01"
  security_enabled = true
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "Terra-Aad-Member-Cod" {
//  for_each = { for i, user in data.azuread_users.users : i => user if user.department == " HR xxxxxxx Programs" }
for_each = { for i, user in data.azuread_user.users : i => user if user.department == "xxxxx" }

  group_object_id  = azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group.object_id
  member_object_id =data.azuread_users.users[each.key].id

}
```

> **Note:** Please make sure you have `User.ReadWrite.All` or
> `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and `Group.ReadWrite.All` , `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All` delegated and
> application permissions to do these operations.

[azuread_users](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/users) |  Terraform Registry doesnot have `department`  attribute but [azuread_user](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/user) | Terraform Registry has department attribute.

[image]